# How I can stop Python Rocket From Appearing in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, macos-catalina, dock

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
from graph_tool import *
from graph_tool import draw


if __name__ == '__main__':


    g = Graph()
    

    v1 = g.add_vertex()
    v2 = g.add_vertex()

    e = g.add_edge(v1, v2)    

    draw.graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, output="two-nodes.pdf")
```

I am using Python 3.8 and I run this code on Mac Os Catalina 10.15.6. My problem is after the line "from graph_tool import draw" is executed, Python rocket appears in Dock. I think it is very annoying and I don't want to see it. I edited the file:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

I added "LSUIElement
1" at the end of the file, just before "
". However, this did not resolve the problem. If anyone knows how I can prevent that annoying rocket from appearing, it will be highly appreciated.

With my respects

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

try

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It's important that the first two lines come *before* the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.
This seems to be an issue with python on OS X, especially with matplotlib.
By Default, on OS X, matplotlib uses the `macosx` backend which is a interactive Backend(Which causes the rocket ship). This Code changes the default backend to the `Agg` backend, which is non-interactive. 

You can find more details on https://leancrew.com/all-this/2014/01/stopping-the-python-rocketship-icon/